# I want to convert .log file to .csv file using python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis, logfile

I have given an alert-handler-error.log file to make analytics on error occurrence. Initially, I have to convert the .log file to CSV or excel file to open it in a data visualization tool.

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-02-03T19:38:10.141Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Heartbeat(key: 12, version: 3)","broker":"64.227.156.112:9092","clientId":"chiefnet-client","error":"The group is rebalancing, so a rejoin is needed","correlationId":51,"size":10}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-02-03T19:38:10.145Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Heartbeat(key: 12, version: 3)","broker":"64.227.156.112:9092","clientId":"chiefnet-client","error":"The group is rebalancing, so a rejoin is needed","correlationId":52,"size":10}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-02-03T19:38:10.147Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Heartbeat(key: 12, version: 3)","broker":"64.227.156.112:9092","clientId":"chiefnet-client","error":"The group is rebalancing, so a rejoin is needed","correlationId":53,"size":10}
```

I tried to read the lines and convert them using the below code

```py
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/admin/alert-log/alerthandlerlog/CN-prod-alert-handler-error.log',sep='\s\s+',engine = 'python')
df.to_csv('my_file.csv',index = None)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your desired result is a dataframe with each key in its own column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you want a dataframe with each unique key as a header item, here you go:

### Imports:

```py
import re
import json
import pandas as pd
```

### Get the JSON objects:

> If you already have them in a list, skip this part

```py
txt = ""
with open('alert-handler-error.log', 'r') as file:
    txt = file.read()
list_of_jsons = []
for match in re.findall(r"(\{.+\})", txt):
  j = json.loads(match)
  list_of_jsons.append(j)
```

### Use your list of JSON objects to init your dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(jsons)
df.to_csv("my_file.csv",index = None)
```

### Result:

[image: result]